# Migrating from one aws elasticsearch cluster to another aws elasticsearch cluster in different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I am trying to move data from one aws elasticsearch cluster in oregon to another aws elasticsearch cluster in N.Virginia. I have registered the repository in source ES and taken a manual snapshot to s3(in Oregon). Now i am trying to register a repository in destination ES in the same s3 location but it is not letting me do it.
Its throwing up an error that the s3 bucket should be in the same region.
I am now stuck. Can anybody suggest a method for this?

Comment: Copy the backup from bucket in  oregon to bucket in N.Virginia, and then restore using the second bucket.

Comment: I am trying that now. I think i tried it once and it failed. But let me try again. If it works, will let you know. You can post your answer and i will mark it.

Comment: It should work. This is the way of doing it. If its not working, maybe there are some other issues, like you use encrypted buckets - then some more exercise is needed.

Comment: @Marcin. It worked. Thanks for the solution. The attempt which failed for me had some error copying the files thats why it was failing. Please post your answer and i will mark it

Comment: Good to hear. The answer was posted. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the solution is to make a backup of the cluster into a bucket in Oregon, copy it from the bucket  to a bucket in N.Virginia, and then restore the cluster in the N.Virginia region using the second bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe no one mentions this on the several instances of this question, but I finally got the desired result. There is a much easier way of doing this:

1. Create an Opensearch VPC Endpoint for your domain on the destination VPC ([Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/vpc-interface-endpoints.html))
2. Either use [Elasticdump](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump), which lets you send/receive to files, buckets or even directly from cluster to cluster, or the AWS-recommended method using [snapshots](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/opensearch-migrate-domain).

Remember to use `https://` else it won't resolve.